# How can I paginate like: Prev 4 5 6 7 Next

Tags: cakephp, paginator

I have a problem with this paginate in Cakephp. Please show me how to do this!
My problem is:
+ In normal: the page numbers are: 
       Prev **1** 2 3 4 Next

- When user press from 1 to 4, the page numbers are not changed.
- When user press the **Next** button, I want the page numbers must be: 
     Prev **5** 6 7 8 Next
- But now they are:
     Prev 3 4 **5** 6 Next

How can I move the number 5 leftmost when I press the **Next** button

I'm using the $this->Paginator->numbers to generate page number, how can I config this?

Please help me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't "move" the number, but start the nav-paging call at the current page.
It is done by providing `options` to the `numbers()` function (`first` and `last` to be specific).

check it here: http://api.cakephp.org/class/paginator-helper#method-PaginatorHelpernumbers

Comment: Thanks for replying me. But my customer need their website looks like this. :(

Comment: please read the link, IT IS the answer for your question. you simply should "get" the page you are in and set it as the "first" option.

Comment: Thanks, but when I'm being in page 8, I try to set first = 8, and the result is there are 8 page before the page 8.